# Reading sequence of ints from a binary file

Tags: haskell, file-io

I have a binary file containing a sequence of 32-bit ints. How do I go about reading them into an list (or Data.Array, which I'll probably end up using)?

All I can find in the documentation is this hGetBuf function, and it isn't clear how to go about use it (requires a Ptr to a buffer?). http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.3.1.0/System-IO.html#v:hGetBuf

Surely there must be a simple approach, but I can't find it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file is just 32-bit ints, then heed @TomMD's warning. Something like this should do the job.

```
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Data.Binary
import Data.Binary.Get
import Data.Binary.Put
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.Int
import System.Posix

testPut = BL.writeFile "foo.bin" . runPut . mapM_ put $ nums
  where nums :: [Int32]
        nums = [5,6,7,8]

testGet :: IO [Int32]
testGet = do n <- fromInteger . toInteger . fileSize <$> getFileStatus "foo.bin"
             let readInts = runGet (replicateM (n `div` 4) get)
             readInts . BL.fromChunks . (:[]) <$> BS.readFile "foo.bin"
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony! What's the point of `BL.fromChunks . (:[]) <$> . BS.readFile` here? Why not just `BL.readFile`?

Comment: @masonk It's probably superfluous. I'm not sure what my intention was with writing it that way.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this quite easily with the `binary` package. You can find the file-reading documentation [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/binary/0.5.0.1/doc/html/Data-Binary.html).

It already includes a way to deserialize a list of 32-bit integers, so you would just need to do call the `decodeFile` function. You may want to have a typed-version of it for clarity:

```
decodeIntsFile :: FilePath -> IO [Int32]
decodeIntsFile = decodeFile
```

Then if you want your list of integers as an array, use the appropriate array conversion, such as `listArray`.

Comment: @oadams Be warned!  The `Binary` instance for `[Int32]` expects a particular format (namely, the file starts with a field indicating the length of the list).  If your file isn't in that format (perhaps it's just raw 32 bit values until EOF?) then you can still using `binary`, but not the pre-defined list instance.